# How to stop Entity framework from inserting associated entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am having problems when trying to insert an entity with null associated entities..

I am just doing :

```
pUser.DogAndUser = null //dogAndUser is the relationship between dog and user 
context.User.Add(pUser)
```

But here I am getting an error saying that the foreign key idDog does not exist in the table Dog. 
And well..of course not..I am giving it a null association..Then I confirmed it was trying to insert the associated entities inserting a row in Dog and then passing the value in the DogAndUser relationship..which did not throw an error and did insert a row in the relationship..but why? I did not explicitly told it to do so..how can I stop this from happening? Thanks!

Comment: Is your foreign key column nullable in the database?

Comment: Nope..but still..why does it try to insert on an associated entity? It is a one to many relationship

Comment: This is because of the defined relations in the dB that is being carried to the EF via EDMX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check a couple of thing to correct the problem.

1. Is the foreign key column is set to nullable in the database?
2. In your model, is the property of the foreign key field nullable
3. On your association, is the End Multiplicity of the DogUAndUser set to 0..1

According to your description, this should correct your problem.